# arcpy SearchCursor, SQL statement invalid

Tags: python, sql, cursor, max, arcpy

I'm trying to select the max(and min in a separate code block, not shown) of values from 3 columns. I'm trying to model my code after some working code I saw with a search cursor.

I need to be able to access whatever the max value is later to write to a file.

The problem is my SQL expression in the search cursor. I've tried about 5 variations that I can think of but none of them will run. I don't know a lot about SQL expressions, but I can usually at least get them right in the ArcMap GUI. In a python script its like finding a snake in the dark.

Here's my code:

```
    #input shapefile
inputFC = 'C:whatever.shp'

#variable to define the field names
fields = ['Crude_R1', 'Crude_R2', 'Crude_R3', 'STATE_NAME', 'Age_Adj_R1', 'Age_Adj_R2', 'Age_Adj_R3']

CRmax = 0

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputFC, fields[0:2], 'MAX "Crude_R1" AND "Crude_R2" AND "Crude_R3"')
for row in cursor:
    print row[0:2]
CRmax = row[0:2]
del row
del cursor
```

Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\whatever.py", line 64, in <module>
for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with you SQL.  If you need help with the statement, add your data schema and a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish.  If you are new to python and arcpy then you may want to use the GUI interface to get the SQL working and then copy it into the python script.

Comment: Alright, well the data is in the attribute table of the shapefile. What I'm trying to do with the SQL is get the MAX value of 3 columns in the table. I hope that is a sufficient explanation since I can't show the data. Not the MAX value of each column but the MAX of all 3 combined. Maybe I'm being too parsimonious and I need to do it more piece-wise. I just am not sure how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

By using the "AND" multiple times such as in:

```
'MAX "Crude_R1" AND "Crude_R2" AND "Crude_R3"'
```

You need to include 'MAX' after each 'AND':

```
'MAX "Crude_R1" AND MAX "Crude_R2" AND MAX "Crude_R3"'
```

Note: there may need to be additional formatting with quotes, but this is the gist of it.
Additionally, try using 'OR' if needed instead of 'AND'.

Secondly, since you specified you want the MAX of the all three field combined, then you will need to first add those field together by creating a new field, then calculating that field as:

```
"!Crude_R1! + !Crude_R2 + !Crude_R2!"
```

Then you can do an SQL statement of simply:

```
'MAX "New_Field"'
```